# VB.NET HTML Decoding in Gridview

Tags: vb.net, gridview, html-encode

So, I'm having difficulty decoding text in a VB GridView. Currently I have the following code:

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    For Each cell As TableCell In e.Row.Cells
        For Each ctrl As Control In cell.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
                Dim txtControl As TextBox = DirectCast(ctrl, TextBox)
                txtControl.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(txtControl.Text)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

But the text in "view" mode is still HTML encoded while in "edit" mode they are decoded.

How do I get it so it is decoded in both modes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
If e.Row.RowIndex = Me.Gridview1.EditIndex Then
'Edit Mode

Else
'Not edit mode

End If
```

To determine if you are in edit mode before you set the text.